# how do i enforce precision on a string containing a double value in c++

Tags: c++, c, string, double, precision

Sample input string:

```
char *str = "12345.567675";
```

And the desired output if I need the precision of 3 places after decimal point:

```
str = "12345.568";
```

Is there a way to do this without converting the string to `double` and back to string?

Comment: Of course he wants, that's obvious even without the example...

Comment: @UmNyobe yes rounding as well.

Comment: Converting makes this so much easier. By is this not wanted?

Comment: If you want rounding, you will need to have some sort of numerics involved, and I bet atof plus other library functions will be faster than you, especially considering something like 0.9999 where you want to get 1.000, so the problem is not even localized around the decimal point. Is it a homework??

Comment: @eudoxos: It's not hard to round fast without numerics, and will definitely be faster. (Unless you need to add a digit to the left)

Comment: @MooingDuck: Talk is cheap, show the code. He will spend 1 day to get the code right and (which I doubt, though) save a few microseconds. Do you think those programming string-to-number conversions were bad programmers? That using rounding instructions is slower than programming something similar? Funny. That's why I asked if it was a homework.

Comment: @eudoxos: Oh, you're right that I only considered runtime.  Good call.  The serialization of double->string is by _far_ the easiest way.  You can make a version that's faster at runtime, but it'll take hours or days of coding to get it right, and the difference would be so small nobody will be able to tell the difference anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah, on high level:
1. search '.' in the string.
2. if the position of '.' + 3 is smaller than the length you done.
3. otherwise, concat the string in the position of '.' + 3.
4. here is tricky: you need to check the next char if exists, ('.' + 4), and if it's value >= 5 goto 4.1 (otherwise goto 5)
4.1. copy the string to a new string that have one more space on the left (cause 9.9999 will be changed to 10.0000 in the '4' loop) and set a pointer (P) to the last char in that string.
4.2. if *P between 0 to 8 add 1 to it and go to 5.
4.3. if *P is 9, set it to zero, move the pointer one left (-1) and goto 4.2
4.4. if *P is '.', move the pointer one left (-1) and goto 4.2
5. remove all the 0 on the right of the decimal point (and the decimal point it self if needed) and you done!!!
6. delete everything, and use the double conversion method...

Comment: This will not round the resulting string properly, e.g. `0.9999`, rounding at third digit should give `1.000`

Comment: it will, read bolt number 4: `...which can cause in some scenario to go from right to left over your number and add 1 to each char.`

Comment: saying is one thing, doing is another

Comment: everything in my answer is in algorithm level. and I'm not saying the implementing it will be easy. I'm just saying what's need to be done and when. in the end, I believe it's to complex and if possible the conversion (double <-> string) should be reconsidered.

Comment: then you should really delete your answer because it is quite obvious. (step 4) is what an algorithm is needed for.

Comment: `2. if *P between 0 to 8 add 1 to it and go to 5.` how is that working with strings?

Comment: @g241 `*p += 1`, then proceed to step 5.

Comment: if (*p >= '0' && *p < '9') *p++;

Comment: @g24l: sue me, I got the capitalization wrong.  The point is that this answer is perfectly valid, and is what I would go with.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel : the problem is that the tag `c++` over there in the question seems to have been ignored (although he is defining a c string) but I would like to add that writing an algorithm of the obvious is not really answering the question. The question is implementation oriented. Also, you are writing "high level" pseudocode that is using low-level notions, such as pointers and char arithmetic which is machine dependent.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a recursion.

```
void roundstr(std::string& strp) {
    char clast;
    char nlast;
    int sl(strp.length()), ipos(0);

    if (strp[sl - 1] == '.') { // skip the dot
        strp.erase(strp.end() - 1);
        nlast='.';
        roundstr(strp);
        return;
    }

    if (strp[sl - 2] == '.') { // handle dot is next char
        ipos = 1;
    }

    if (sl == 1) { // handle first char
        nlast = '0'; // virtual 0 in front of first char
        clast = strp[1];
    } else {
        clast = strp[sl - 1]; // current (last) char
        nlast = strp[sl - 2 - ipos]; // next to last char
    }

    if (clast >= '5') { // need to operate only if meet 5 or larger, otherwise stop
        nlast++;
        strp.erase(strp.end() - 1); // remove the last char from the string
        if (nlast == ':') { // if need to round further
            strp.replace(strp.end() - 1 - ipos, strp.end() - ipos, 1, nlast);
            clast = '0'; // keep current char value
            roundstr(strp);
        } else {
            strp.replace(strp.end() - 1 - ipos, strp.end() - ipos, 1, nlast);
            if(clast==':') clast = '0';
        }
    }

    sl = strp.length();
    if (nlast == ':') {
        if (ipos == 1) {
            strp += '.';
        } else {
            strp += '0';
        }
    } else if (nlast=='.' && strp[sl-1] != '.') {
        strp += '.';
    } else {
        if (ipos == 1 && strp[sl-1]!='.') {
            strp += '.';
        } else {
            strp += clast;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

and you call it like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdlib.h>

void roundstr(std::string&);
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int p;
    std::string strp;

    switch (argc) {
    case 2:
        p = 2;
        break;
    case 3:
        p = atoi(argv[2]);
        strp = argv[1];
        break;
    default:
        return 1;
        break;
    }

    std::cout << strp << " " << p << std::endl;
    roundstr(strp);
    strp.erase(strp.end()-p, strp.end());
    std::cout << strp << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

as you can see you must handle removing the extra digits but it is not difficult to write a wrapper function, or even a class to do this automagicaly during construction.

It may also be possible that this will be faster if done with c-strings instead of `std::string`. In case that you plan to do heavy duty symbolic arithmetic I would advise for replacing all `std::string` and `char` with `char *` but you should be more careful during removal addition of values.

Answer (score 0):

Find the dot in the string. Then, find the fourth character after that position. Return substring from 0 to position of dot + 3, and then adjust the last character - if fourth character after dot in original string is greater than or equal to 5, then increment the last character (or set to '0', if '9' and increment the prievous and so on). If it's less than 5 - do nothing and return just substring of original string.

Although, I think it wouldn't hit the performance if you just converted it to float, use (for example) `boost::format` to get it rounded.

Comment: Don't forget the carry, and the possible requirement of adding a digit to the left.

Answer (score 0):

This casts it to a float first.

```
int main()
{
    std::string f = "12345.567675";

    std::ostringstream ss;
    float x = boost::lexical_cast<float>(f);
    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3);
    ss << x;
    std::string s = ss.str();

    std::cout << s << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the results:

```
./a.out 
12345.567
```

Comment: aren't you converting this back to string from a numeric? what is this? playing with words...it's not tomato, it's a tomAtO ...?

Comment: did you read the question ? 'without converting the string to double and back to string'

Comment: @RoeeGavirel - Yes, but I missed that part.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that you always have a dot and at least 3 digits after it:

```
char *str = "12345.567675";
char *p = str;

while ( *p != '.' )
{
    printf( "%c", *p++ );
    // find a dot
}

for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
{
    printf( "%c", *p++ );
}
```

Comment: So many bad things... A. don't assume it have '.' B. Don't assume it have 3 digit after it C. what about rounding the number...